# How to display the company header only on the first page?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

i want to show the company reportheader only on the first page.I have now beautifull qweb report in PDF. But if my reports (sale order, for example) have more than one page, the header is on EACH page.

How to put company header only on the first page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Header is only displayed once, in first page.report. The others are empty

```python
<template id="report_quotation_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
           <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
        <div class="header">
            <t t-set="data_report_margin_top" t-value="12"/>
            <t t-set="data_report_header_spacing" t-value="9"/>
            <t t-set="data_report_dpi" t-value="110"/>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" name="company_address">
            <div t-field="company.partner_id" 
                t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": true}'
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>  <!-- end teamplate header-->
```

Comment: sorry i want only company address and customer address only  first page

Answer (score 0):

Call your header inside page div. This will print header only on first page of qweb report in odoo

in odoo 10 I have done this as follows:

```
  <template id="custom_report_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header" primary="True">
           <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
                <div class="header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row zero_min_height">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>    
                </xpath>
         </template>   




    <template id="your_custom_header_id" inherit_id="report.external_layout" primary="True">
                <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='report.external_layout_header']" position="replace">
                     <t t-call="your_module_name.custom_report_header" />
                </xpath>

    </template>
    <template id="your_report_name"
                      <t t-call="report.html_container">
               <div class="page">
                     <t t-call="your_module_name.your_custom_header_id">
                     </t>
                     ....
                  </div>
           </t> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

pramod24

You can use the OCA App [Report Qweb Element Page Visibility](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/report_qweb_element_page_visibility/).

You can use this class `first-page` shows an element only on the first page.

Thanks